# Kotlin lazy properties and values reset: a resettable lazy delegate

Tags: android, properties, kotlin, lazy-initialization

So I use `kotlin` for android, and when inflating views, I tend to do the following:

```
private val recyclerView by lazy { find<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView) }
```

This method will work. However, there is a case in which it will bug the app. If this is a fragment, and the fragment goes to the backstack, `onCreateView` will be called again, and the view hierarchy of the fragment will recreated. Which means, the lazy initiated recyclerView will point out to an old view no longer existent.

A solution is like this:

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
```

And initialise all the properties inside `onCreateView`.

My question is, is there any way to reset lazy properties so they can be initialised again? I like the fact initialisations are all done at the top of a class, helps to keep the code organised. The specific problem is found in this question: [kotlin android fragment empty recycler view after back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744969/kotlin-android-fragment-empty-recycler-view-after-back)

Comment: Are you looking for a lazy mutable variable that you can implicitly initialize but can also explicitly set or are you looking for a loading cache that you can reload?

Comment: i want to lazily initialise a property with the option to reset it if needed. Reseting being the state before the first initialisation

Comment: you need a custom delegate for that, it is relatively easy to write. If your scenario is often used, this can even be implemented in stdlib

Comment: it is. The view initialisation in android if often done by: "by lazy {find>View(R.id.viewId)}" but there are cases in which this binding must be reseted. And there is no way of doing that

Comment: What is the value for the variable of "reset"?  null?  You want it to lazy load it again on next access?  Look at implementation of Lazy and `ReadOnlyProperty` for ideas.

Comment: This is not the answer that you want but I suggest you to consider using [Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to find views. You will not need to use lazy nor other crazy logic to reset the lazy object. Also consider that Lazy perform some overheads for concurrency so use it cautiously (see LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE for more details)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a quick version of a resettable lazy, it could be more elegant and needs double checked for thread safety, but this is basically the idea.  You need something to manage (keep track) of the lazy delegates so you can call for reset, and then things that can be managed and reset.  This wraps `lazy()` in these management classes.

**Here is what your final class will look like**, as an example:

```
class Something {
    val lazyMgr = resettableManager()
    val prop1: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { ... }
    val prop2: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { ... }
    val prop3: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { ... }
}
```

**Then to make the lazy's all go back to new values on next time they are accessed:**

```
lazyMgr.reset() // prop1, prop2, and prop3 all will do new lazy values on next access
```

**The implementation of the resettable lazy:**

```
class ResettableLazyManager {
    // we synchronize to make sure the timing of a reset() call and new inits do not collide
    val managedDelegates = LinkedList<Resettable>()

    fun register(managed: Resettable) {
        synchronized (managedDelegates) {
            managedDelegates.add(managed)
        }
    }

    fun reset() {
        synchronized (managedDelegates) {
            managedDelegates.forEach { it.reset() }
            managedDelegates.clear()
        }
    }
}

interface Resettable {
    fun reset()
}

class ResettableLazy<PROPTYPE>(val manager: ResettableLazyManager, val init: ()->PROPTYPE): Resettable {
    @Volatile var lazyHolder = makeInitBlock()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): PROPTYPE {
        return lazyHolder.value
    }

    override fun reset() {
        lazyHolder = makeInitBlock()
    }

    fun makeInitBlock(): Lazy<PROPTYPE> {
        return lazy {
            manager.register(this)
            init()
        }
    }
}

fun <PROPTYPE> resettableLazy(manager: ResettableLazyManager, init: ()->PROPTYPE): ResettableLazy<PROPTYPE> {
    return ResettableLazy(manager, init)
}

fun resettableManager(): ResettableLazyManager = ResettableLazyManager()
```

---

**And some unit tests to be sure:**

```
class Tester {
   @Test fun testResetableLazy() {
       class Something {
           var seed = 1
           val lazyMgr = resettableManager()
           val x: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { "x ${seed}" }
           val y: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { "y ${seed}" }
           val z: String by resettableLazy(lazyMgr) { "z $x $y"}
       }

       val s = Something()
       val x1 = s.x
       val y1 = s.y
       val z1 = s.z

       assertEquals(x1, s.x)
       assertEquals(y1, s.y)
       assertEquals(z1, s.z)

       s.seed++ // without reset nothing should change

       assertTrue(x1 === s.x)
       assertTrue(y1 === s.y)
       assertTrue(z1 === s.z)

       s.lazyMgr.reset()

       s.seed++ // because of reset the values should change

       val x2 = s.x
       val y2 = s.y
       val z2 = s.z

       assertEquals(x2, s.x)
       assertEquals(y2, s.y)
       assertEquals(z2, s.z)

       assertNotEquals(x1, x2)
       assertNotEquals(y1, y2)
       assertNotEquals(z1, z2)

       s.seed++ // but without reset, nothing should change

       assertTrue(x2 === s.x)
       assertTrue(y2 === s.y)
       assertTrue(z2 === s.z)
   }
}
```

Comment: saved me a lot of time thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I find a convenient method:

```kotlin
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

fun <T> resetableLazy(initializer: () -> T) = ResetableDelegate(initializer)

class ResetableDelegate<T>(private val initializer: () -> T) {
    private val lazyRef: AtomicReference<Lazy<T>> = AtomicReference(
        lazy(
            initializer
        )
    )

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return lazyRef.get().getValue(thisRef, property)
    }

    fun reset() {
        lazyRef.set(lazy(initializer))
    }
}
```

test:

```kotlin
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

class ResetableLazyData {
    var changedData = 0
    val delegate = resetableLazy { changedData }
    val readOnlyData by delegate
}

class ResetableLazyTest {

    @Test
    fun testResetableLazy() {
        val data = ResetableLazyData()
        data.changedData = 1
        Assert.assertEquals(data.changedData, data.readOnlyData)
        data.changedData = 2
        Assert.assertNotEquals(data.changedData, data.readOnlyData)
        data.delegate.reset()
        Assert.assertEquals(data.changedData, data.readOnlyData)
        data.changedData = 3
        Assert.assertNotEquals(data.changedData, data.readOnlyData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet, if you don't care about thread safety.  Can be even shorter if you omit the function definition, which doesn't add anything beyond calling the delegate constructor directly.

Comment: This code is not working. I must cast property to ResetableDelegate and then call reset()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task, and this is what I used:

```
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class SingletonLazy<T : Any>(val initBlock: () -> T, val clazz: Class<T>) {
    operator fun <R> provideDelegate(ref: R, prop: KProperty<*>): ReadOnlyProperty<R, T> = delegate()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun <R> delegate(): ReadOnlyProperty<R, T> = object : ReadOnlyProperty<R, T> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T {
            val hash = clazz.hashCode()
            val cached = singletonsCache[hash]
            if (cached != null && cached.javaClass == clazz) return cached as T
            return initBlock().apply { singletonsCache[hash] = this }
        }
    }
}

private val singletonsCache = HashMap<Int, Any>()

fun <T> clearSingleton(clazz: Class<T>) : Boolean {
    val hash = clazz.hashCode()
    val result = singletonsCache[hash]
    if (result?.javaClass != clazz) return false

    singletonsCache.remove(hash)
    return true
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> singletonLazy(noinline block: () -> T): SingletonLazy<T>
        = SingletonLazy(block, T::class.java)
```

usage:

```
val cat: Cat by singletonLazy { Cat() }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    cat
    println(clearSingleton(Cat::class.java))
    cat // cat will be created one more time
    println(singletonsCache.size)
}

class Cat {
    init { println("creating cat") }
}
```

Of course, you may have you own caching strategies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something very simple, extends `Lazy<T>` and yet efficient in few lines of code, you could use this

```
class MutableLazy<T>(private val initializer: () -> T) : Lazy<T> {
    private var cached: T? = null
    override val value: T
        get() {
            if (cached.isNull()) {
                cached = initializer()
            }
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return cached as T
        }

    fun reset() {
        cached = null
    }

    override fun isInitialized(): Boolean = cached != null

    companion object {
        fun <T> resettableLazy(value: () -> T) = MutableLazy(value)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
class MainActivity() {
    val recyclerViewLazy = MutableLazy.resettable {
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    }
    val recyclerView by recyclerViewLazy
    // And later on
    override onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recyclerViewLazy.reset() /** On next get of the recyclerView, it would be updated*/
    }
}
```

Borrowed partly from

> `lazy(`**`LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE`**`) {  }`

provided in the stlib

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`fun <P, T> renewableLazy(initializer: (P) -> T): ReadWriteProperty<P, T> =
    RenewableSynchronizedLazyWithThisImpl({ t, _ ->
        initializer.invoke(t)
    })

fun <P, T> renewableLazy(initializer: (P, KProperty<*>) -> T): ReadWriteProperty<P, T> =
    RenewableSynchronizedLazyWithThisImpl(initializer)

    class RenewableSynchronizedLazyWithThisImpl<in T, V>(
        val initializer: (T, KProperty<*>) -> V,
        private val lock: Any = {}
    ) : ReadWriteProperty<T, V> {

    @Volatile
    private var _value: Any? = null

    override fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>): V {
        val _v1 = _value
        if (_v1 !== null) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return _v1 as V
        }

        return synchronized(lock) {
            val _v2 = _value
            if (_v2 !== null) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (_v2 as V)
            } else {
                val typedValue = initializer(thisRef, property)
                _value = typedValue
                typedValue
            }
        }
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>, value: V) {
        // 不论设置何值，都会被重置为空
        synchronized(lock) {
            _value = null
        }
    }
    }`