# Kotlin var lazy init

Tags: delegates, kotlin

I want to do a lazy initialization for a `var` property. Since `by lazy` is restricted only to `val` properties I have to write something like this:

```
    private var currentContextProvider: ContextProvider? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                field = DefaultContextProvider()
            }
            return field
        }
```

And now I have to deal with those **pointless** nullability-aware calls: `currentContextProvider?.getContext()` or alternatively `currentContextProvider!!.getContext()`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it sounds like you're interested in two things happening: `nullability` and `initialization`. Does your variable have to be nullable? Do you want to initialize this item once and only once? Also, why do you want `var` and not `val` specifically?

Comment: I'm sure someone will post a code on how to implement a custom delegate but I can't imagine any real life situation where you need to make a lazy property modifiable without compromising encapsulation

Comment: @dkarmazi I create a strategy where the default one is `DefaultContextProvider`. That's why I use `var` instead of `val` so I can change it in runtime. I also want to provide a stub strategy (not to mock the whole class) and test all the things. My test dependencies distinguish from the prod ones so it throws an error when it reaches `DefaultContextProvider()`. That's the reason of a lazy init. I set the stub strategy in `onSetup` before any call to this class and it goes ok except I have to deal with nullability-aware issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin lazy properties and values reset: a resettable lazy delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752575/kotlin-lazy-properties-and-values-reset-a-resettable-lazy-delegate)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of making it nullable, you can decide to initialise it with some default value, which on first access will be replaced with the lazily calculated value:

```
private val noInit = "noinit"
var currentContextProvider: String = noInit
        get() = if (field == noInit) {
            synchronized(this) {
                return if (field == noInit) "lazyinit" else field
            }
        } else field
```

(I've replaced the `ContextProvider` with `String`)

#### Custom Delegate

The following implements a [custom delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) reusing the former solution. It can be used just like `lazy()` by defining `var currentContextProvider: ContextProvider by LazyMutable { DefaultContextProvider() }`

```
class LazyMutable<T>(val initializer: () -> T) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private object UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
    private var prop: Any? = UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return if (prop == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
            synchronized(this) {
               return if (prop == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) initializer().also { prop = it } else prop as T
            }
        } else prop as T
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        synchronized(this) {
            prop = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw lazy() at least implements infamous double checked locking - if you open Lazy.kt source code you'll see it's pretty sophisticated

Comment: tbh I thought it will be a reusable custom delegate :)

Comment: there you go, not as sophisticated as lazy though ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't we save the value in a backing field here:
`return if (prop == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) initializer() else prop as T` but not just give it away?
Otherwise it runs `initializer()` every call (until we explicitly set the value)

Comment: You're right, sorry I missed that part, fixed with `return if (prop == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) initializer().also { prop = it } else prop as T
`

Comment: Is it also possible to call `fun isInitialized(): Boolean` like here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/index.html ? I couldn't find a way to do so...

Comment: Note that the inline solution (the first code block - without the delegate) would also need a backing property if you use an initializer, to avoid having the initializer be called each time the property is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a lazy delegated property that initializes and caches when you `get` the property, but allows you to set it to `null` to remove that cached result (and  re-`initialize()` it when you `get` it again).

Thanks to the above answer for the code so I could tweak it.

```kotlin
@Suppress("ClassName")
class lazyNullCacheable<T>(val initializer: () -> T) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private object UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
    private var prop: Any? = UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return if (prop == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE || prop == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                initializer().also { prop = it }
            }
        } else prop as T
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        synchronized(this) {
            prop = value
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```kotlin
var prop: String? by lazyNullCacheable {
    "string"
}

prop // get prop
prop = null // when you're done using it and want to recalculate / cache it next time
prop // get prop, it will initialize() and cache again
```

Functionally equivalent to doing something like this (but this is uglier imho)

```kotlin
var _prop: Type? = null
val prop: Type
    get() = _prop ?: run {
        _prop = Type()
        _prop!!
    }

prop // get result
_prop = null // clear cache
prop // next get will recalculate it
```

Comment: why synchronized ?

Comment: @Renetik This is just a copy of the accepted answer, with some small tweaking done to make it work slightly differently (calculate on get, clear on null, and recalculate on get). I'm not sure why they used `synchronized`, but I imagine it's important if you want to use this from different threads

Comment: sure I realized later that original kotlin lazy implementation is also synchronized so ti makes sense...

Comment: I thin you might want to reconsider such a design because it violates principle of least surprise - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment. Setting `prop = null` to null, and not getting null back in next statement will surprise the API user.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
class LazyMutable<T>(
    val initializer: () -> T,
) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private val lazyValue by lazy { initializer() }
    private var newValue: T? = null

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) =
        newValue ?: lazyValue

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        newValue = value
    }
}
```

usage:

```kotlin
var foo by LazyMutable { "initial value" }
```

(doesn't support nullable `foo`)

Answer (score 0):

**Test:**

```
class LazyVarTest {

    @Test
    fun testLazyVar() {
        var testVar: String by lazyVar { "initial" }
        assertEquals("initial", testVar)
        testVar = "test"
        assertEquals("test", testVar)
    }

    @Test
    fun testNullableLazyVar() {
        var testVar: String? by lazyVar { "initial" }
        assertEquals("initial", testVar)
        testVar = "test"
        assertEquals("test", testVar)
        testVar = null
        assertEquals(null, testVar)
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
fun <T> lazyVar(initializer: () -> T) = LazyVar(initializer)

class LazyVar<T>(initializer: () -> T) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private object initialValue

    var isSet = false
    private val lazyValue by lazy { initializer() }
    private var value: Any? = initialValue

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T =
        synchronized(this) {
            if (!isSet) return lazyValue
            return value as T
        }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) =
        synchronized(this) {
            this.value = value
            isSet = true
        }
}
```