# How to initialize lateinit variable in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I want get "id" from data class cartDocs in this Activity.
 I am trying to run this code, but got error like this:
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cart has not been initialized
I also tried to remove "?" in data class. but still same problem.
How can I solve this problem?

```
class CartViewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {




    lateinit var cart: cartDocs

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_view)

        val token = SharedPreference.getTokenInfo(this)

        Client.retrofitService.getCart(token).enqueue(object :Callback<CartResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<CartResponse>, response: Response<CartResponse>) {
                swipeRefreshLo.setOnRefreshListener(this@CartViewActivity)
                showdata(response.body()?.docs!!)
                val itemId = cart.id
                if (itemId!=null){
                    SharedPreference.setCartId(applicationContext,itemId)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CartResponse>, t: Throwable) {

            }


        })
```

data class cartDocs

```
data class cartDocs(

    var id:String?=null,

    var title:String?=null,

    var stock:Int?=null,

    var availableAfter:String?=null,

    var price:Int?=null,

    var point:Int?=null,

    var mainImage:String?=null,

    var description:MutableList<cartDescription>,

    var amount:Int?=null,

    var added:String?=null,

    var options:MutableList<cartOptions>,

    var unitPrice:Int?=null,

    var unitPoint:Int?=null,

    var totalPrice:Int?=null,

    var totalPoint:Int?=null
)
```

Comment: It's `cart` which is not initialized.

Comment: Nullable types (`?`) don't generate this error.

Comment: So How can cart initialized ??

Comment: By assigning to it. `cart = cartDocs()`.

Comment: `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` should already raise suspicion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lateinit` was designed for cases when you need to init a variable some time after object creation - for example frameworks like `dagger`. In fact it allows to use `lateinit` variable as normal `not null` value (and get rid of unnecessary `?/!!` operators) but the programmer is responsible to make sure that value is initialized before the use.

In your case you try to use that variable before it's initialized. So, you get  given exception. What you need is to initialize that value at some point. But, I would think about the design - seems that what you need is a `nullable` type and using `lateinit` here is not reasonable. It will enforce on you checking if value is not null before any use of that value.

If you are interested in `lateinit` design in JVM you can see my old answer to other question: [How to uninitialize lateinit in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335188/how-to-uninitialize-lateinit-in-kotlin/58337067#58337067)