# How to clear data from kotlin object?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to know how to clear the data from the object which is already assigned with some value in it.
**Example**

```
var myObject : String = "some_data"
myObject.clear() // I need to clear the information present in it.
::myObject.isInitialized // It must return false
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337067/1117696

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want. `isInitialized` will always return `true` as soon as  `lateinit` property was initialized. For this purpose, Kotlin has `?` to mark a type as optional type.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare variable as `nullable` and then assign null.

```
var myObject : String? = "some_data"
myObject = null // clear data
```

then you can reassign value to it:

```
myObject = "another_date"
```

`?` indicates it is nullable variable.

also you can use `lateinit` syntax in some purpose. Look at this topic:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables

Comment: i don't want myObject to make nullable type.

Comment: maybe you should use **lateinit** or reassign "" and check if not blank and use `isBlank()` and `isNotBlank()` methods.